# parse error seems to depend on what I name my array index

Tags: php, string, echo, associative-array

I am new to PHP. When I use "echo" to print an array element, my success seems to depend on what I name the index. That can't be right, right?! I feel like I am going crazy. This code:

```
$ARRAY['q1'] = 'foo';
echo "q1 is $ARRAY[q1]<br>";
```

Works fine.  But this code:

```
$ARRAY['1q'] = 'foo';
echo "1q is $ARRAY[1q]<br>";
```

Produces the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 6

I know that I can correct the problem like this:

```
echo "1q is " . $ARRAY['1q'] . "<br>";
```

But my question is WHY would the array index "1q" vs. "q1" matter in the first code block?  I even checked to see if 1q is a constant of some kind but it doesn't seem to be. Is this an improper way to insert an array element in a string? (I copied it from the PHP documentation.)

This is in PHP 5.3.8.  I really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**
Ok I got this echo syntax from Example #8 on this page of the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php  Apparently it is not the right way to do things.  I will add a user-contributed note to the manual.

An entire script that produces this error would be:

```
<?php
$ARRAY['1q'] = 'foo';
echo "1q is $ARRAY[1q]<br>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Which line is `line 6`? Please show the full actual code that is producing the error, there are no syntax errors above - although if you want to use an associative array value directly in a string, the correct syntax is `"q1 is {$ARRAY['q1']}<br>"`.

Comment: normally, the variables must start with `alphabets` or `_` characters, not numerals.

Comment: I think Chasing Death's comment is actually the best answer, although it is not an answer so I can't mark it that way. I just looked it up and it says very clearly in the PHP manual that you can't start a variable name with a number.  Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using arrays in a double-quoted string, if PHP sees the array key start with a number, it assumes the entire key is a numeric index, e.g.

```
echo "$arr[123abc]";
```

is interpreted as `$arr[123]`. The `abc` portion is what's producing the expected string error, since a numeric key can't contain non-numeric components.

To fix this, you'll have to use

```
echo "1q is {$ARRAY['1q]'}<br>";
            ^       ^   ^^
```

with properly quoted array indexes

Answer (score 3):

Because it's trying to treat the array key as a literal of some kind. For `q1` this works because there is no constant named `q1` so PHP assumes it's supposed to be a string. `1q`, however, fails because it starts looking at it as a number.

You should not embed arrays in strings like that anyway. Use one of the following:

```
echo "1q is {$ARRAY['1q']}";
echo "1q is ".$ARRAY['1q'];
```

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have thought this would cause a parse error, but [apparently](http://codepad.org/wc8LtA3w) it [does](http://codepad.org/qQouZwNS). I would have thought that `$ARRAY[1q]` would appear literally in the string or it would work. I suppose this is why the PHP naming conventions don't allow numeric digits at the first character position...

Comment: DaveRandom, if it helps, here's a complete script:
    <?php
    $ARRAY['1q'] = 'foo';
    echo "1q is $ARRAY[1q]<br>";
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate. Try `echo "1q is {$ARRAY['1q']}";`.

- You should always use quotes for accessing string array keys, even inside strings.
- Its a good practice to embrace variables on {} inside strings.